# Polynomials considered as multisets of roots: extend polynomial addition and derivation to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots, multisets

**Informal context**

In $\mathbb{C}[X]$, all polynomials are split, so monic polynomials are in bijection with the multisets of their roots, i.e. the finite sub-multisets of $\mathbb{C}$.
Polynomial multiplication corresponds to multiset union.

To define a polynomial, we need a ring (and to get always-split polynomials we need an algebraically closed field). But to define multisets, we need nothing at all except a set! So **we can define monic "polynomials" with their multiplication in any set we want**.

How far can we get this? We'd like to have addition and derivation, how can we define them with multisets?

**First steps**

We need to get all the polynomials, not merely monic ones, because addition and derivation are not stable inside monic polynomials.

So we need a scaling factor. Looking at the way addition and derivation behave, the scalar set could be $\mathbb{Z}$ or anything bigger. Let's take $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's consider ***weighted multisets***, i.e. if $E$ is the set of values, $M$ the set of multisets of $E$, and $\mathbb{R}^* $ is the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, we define weighted multisets on $E$ as $W = \mathbb{R}^* \times M \cup (0, \emptyset)$.

- A polynomial $\lambda (X-a_1)(X-a_2)...(X-a_n)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is represented by $(\lambda, \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\})$.
- The constant $\lambda$ is represented by $(\lambda, \emptyset)$.

Multiplication of polynomials is union of weighted multisets, with the coefficients being multiplied, i.e. $(\lambda, \{a_1, ..., a_n\}) \cup (\mu, \{b_1, ..., b_m\}) = (\lambda \mu, \{a_1, ..., a_n, b_1, ..., b_m\})$.

**Question**

How can we use these weighted multisets to provide the ***equivalent of polynomial addition, multiplication and derivation, for spaces such as $\mathbb{R}^n, n>2$, while continuously extending the polynomial operations on $\mathbb{R}^2$*** (being identified with $\mathbb{C}$)?

- addition and multiplication shall have commutative ring properties;
- derivation of an $n$ multiset shall be an $n-1$ multiset;
- derivation shall verify the usual sum and product derivation rules;
- when all roots are in a (2-dim) plane of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the results of addition or derivation shall be the same as in $\mathbb{C}$ (*);
- continuity is for a distance on same-size multisets, such as: if $A=(a_i)$ and $B=(b_i)$ are $2$ multisets with $n$ elements, $d(A,B)=\min_{\sigma \in S_n} \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert a_i-b_{\sigma(i)} \rVert$.

(*) Note that in $\mathbb{C}$, derivation commutes with all geometric similarities: if polynomial $Q$ is polynomial $P$ translated or rotated or symmetrized or scaled, roots of $Q'$ are roots of $P'$ transformed by the same translation/rotation/symmetry/scaling. So when considering derivation in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if we take a multiset which is entirely contained in a (2-dim) plane, the derivation operation has only one possible result, whatever basis we choose to identify the plane with $\mathbb{C}$. The same can be said about addition. So "extending the polynomial operations on $\mathbb{R}^2$" above is well defined.

Getting ***addition*** seems difficult: there is no simple way to deduce roots of $P+Q$ from roots of $P$ and roots of $Q$, except in the most simple of cases, e.g. if $P=\alpha(X-a), Q=\beta(X-b),$
$P+Q=(\alpha+\beta)X-(\alpha a + \beta b) = (\alpha+\beta)(X-\frac {\alpha a + \beta b} {\alpha+\beta})$
In terms of weighted multisets, this is a barycenter operation. Unfortunately this does not extend to degree $2$ and above polynomials.

Getting ***derivation*** may use Bôcher's theorem: zeros of $P'$ which are not also zeros of $P$, are the equilibrium points of an $\frac 1 r$ force field created by particles of same mass on zeros of $P$. This could be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$, but do we have the property that $p$ distinct zeros of $P$ create $p-1$ equilibrium points?

Comment: I wish I had the knowledge to understand this question :c

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom That's less a question of knowledge, than a question of the OP providing good explanations, and I fear I may have failed at that, sorry.